# How to annotate a Kotlin class constructor that might throw an exception?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I would like to keep my Kotlin data class as simple as possible. It is initialized only from a `JSONObject` like this:

```kotlin
data class Foo(val json: JSONObject)
{
    @JvmField val bar: String = json.getString("bar")
}
```

Is there any way to annotate the class, that the constructor might throw a `JSONException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, your class declaration has an [implicit primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)

You can annotate the constructor after you define that explicitly:

```kotlin
data class Foo @Throws(JSONException::class) constructor(val json: JSONObject)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, they are all very helpful but only seconds apart. I chose to accept this one, because the link provides further information.

Answer (score 5):

I think

```kotlin
class Foo @Throws(JSONException::class) constructor(val json: JSONObject) { 
 // code 
}
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

The same way you do for a function:

```kotlin
import kotlin.jvm.Throws

class Foo @Throws(JSONException::class) constructor(val json: JSONObject) {
    
    init {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This becomes the following Java signature:

```java
public Foo(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
```